# PHP MVC Model and RedBeanPHP - Associations

Tags: php, activerecord, redbean

I'm building a custom MVC framework partially based on CakePHP and using RedBeanPHP.

Now I'm in the part of creating the DB CRUD. Here's my idea:

```
class Model extends RedBean_SimpleModel {

}


class Product extends Model {

var $beans = array(
'name',
'price',
...
);
}
```

This seems a good way to make RedBeanPHP generate the table "Products" and columns on the fly.

Now my current doubt (since I'm starting to work and understand RedBeanPHP) problem is the associations.

I really like the [CakePHP's](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) method, with "hasOne", "hasMany", "belongsTo", etc.

Can someone guide me to a way of doing that but with RedBeanPHP?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use up-front models with RedBeanPHP. RedBeanPHP can connect your beans automatically for you using a system called FUSE.
This saves a lot of code. And... less code == less bugs

```
$p = R::dispense('product');
$p->price = -6; //not a valid price
R::store($p);
```

Later you want to add validation and you write:

```
class Model_Product extends RedBean_SimpleModel {
    public function update() {
        if ($this->price < 0) throw new Exception('Price cant be negative!');
    ...}
}
```

RedBeanPHP will connect the product bean $p with the model Model_Product in your domain model. You can also add new methods and call them using the bean:

```
$p->play(); //-- will call play() on Model_Product
```

Read more about Fuse:

http://www.redbeanphp.com/how_fuse_works

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for RedBeanPHP and your answer. I updated my code in the question to better reflect what I have (FUSE). The creation of columns and tables and respective columns on-the-fly brings a problem, that is the [Cold start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_start). Meaning that I'll have to create PHP code (model) to prepare the creation of non-existing tables, columns and associations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do relationships with redbean.

```
$child->parent=$parentBean; // parent relationship
$child->ownToy=array($toybean1,$toybean2); // 1 to many relationship
$child->sharedToy=array($toybean1,$toybean2); // many to many relationship
```

So the question now is, how are you going to implement that?  You can have something like:

```
var $relations=array(
    'fieldname'=>array('hasMany','names')
);
```

Then when you handle the save, just make sure you are calling the correct functions:

```
if(array_key_exists('fieldname',$this->relations)){
//magic happens
}
```

Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your answer. Surely as made me understand better how associations work in RedBeanPHP.